# Perl rewrite old URLS to seo friendly

Tags: regex, perl, nginx, url-rewriting, seo

I am trying to fix my old URLS which have bad characters in them for  all .html request

I want to replace the following instance with a dash (`-`):

- Space
- Comas
- Plus signs
- Parentheses
- Apostrophes
- Double dashes with a single dash
- Then all Upper and lower cases

The following has been implemented and is not working on the sever

I've re-written the perl fragment nginx is using as follows:

```
perl_set $old_uri 'sub {
my $r = shift;
my $uri = $r->uri;

$uri = lc $uri;
$uri =~ s/[+, ()\']/-/g;
$uri =~ s/--+/-/g;

return $uri;
}';
```

This is switching everything to lowercase, converting the requested symbols to dashes, then compacting multiple dashes in a row into one

The perl rules for this are

```
    perl_set $old_uri 'sub {
    my $r = shift;
    my $uri = $r->uri;

    $uri = lc $uri; # Upper to lower
    $uri =~ s/[^a-z0-9-.\/]/-/g;
    $uri =~ s/--+/-/g; # turn double -- to -

    return $uri;
   }';
```

The location block which calls this is

```
  location ~ [^a-z0-9-.\/].*.html {
        rewrite ^ $old_uri permanent;
    }
```

Let me know if I need to provide more info

Comment: Can you give an example of a URI and what it rewrites to?

Comment: i have a few bad urls so here is some that are bad ones domain.com/DVDC/Yes+man's house.html need to be redirected to domain.com/dvdc/yes-man-s-house.html

Answer (score 0):

You can replace any special character into dash/hyphen

```
$url=~ s/\W+/-/g;
```